# Query to find for each CEO, the number of store types, and the max item number among its cities

Tags: mysql, sql

```
Store_Type  CEO_Name       *Table Store*        
Store1      CEO1            
Store2      CEO1            
Store3      CEO2            
Store4      CEO2            
Store5      CEO2            
Store6      CEO3            



City        Store_Type  Items          *Table City*
NY          Store1      8000000     
DC          Store1      600000      
Philly      Store1      1500000     
Ottawa      Store2      800000      
Tortonto    Store2      2500000     
Berlin      Store4      3500000     
Hamburg     Store4      2000000     
Bonn        Store4      300000      
Paris       Store5      2000000     
Lyon        Store5      700000      
Bamako      Store6      2000000     
Timbuktu    Store6      50000       
Mopti       Store6      100000
```

From inspecting the tables, the result should be similar to this: The output is for each CEO, it list's the number of store types for that CEO and the max item number among its cities

```
CE01        2             8000000
CEO2        2 (3?)        3500000
CE03        1             2000000
```

I have tried multiple ways to do this and failed. I know that I can use COUNT(Store_Type) for counting how many store types each CEO has, but since there are duplicates, it's getting difficult to make this 3 column table so to speak. Then MAX(items) will be used but it has to be the max for the CEO as a whole.

I tried breaking it up but I kept getting group errors continuously. Here are some examples I managed to write down but I did try multiple brute forces in the command line once I thought I had an "epiphany" and changed tactics so I don't have those saved. Those mainly encompassed lots of tries with joins but I still couldn't achieve what I wanted to do. Hence, why I am here now asking a simple SQL question.

```
    select distinct B.CEO_Name
    from Store B, City C
    where B.Store_Type=C.Store_Type;
    -----
    select distinct B.CEO_Name
    from Store B, City C
    where B.Store_Type=C.Store_Type;
    INTERSECT 
    select COUNT(distinct Store_Type)
    from City;
    -----
    select distinct C.Store_Type, D.CEO, COUNT(distinct C.Store_Type)
    from City C, Store D
    where C.Store_Type=D.Store_Type;
    ------
    select D.CEO, COUNT(C.Store_Type)
    from Store D, City C
    where D.Store_Type=C.Store_Type;
    ------
    select D.CEO, COUNT(C.Store_Type)
    from Store D full outer join City C
    on (D.Store_Type=C.Store_Type);
```

Comment: post your tables and data as text

Comment: @e4c5 I just updated it.

Comment: where does that second column come from/

Comment: @e4c5 Are you referring to 2 2 1? That is how many store types that CEO has. For example, CEO1 has 2 store types (store1 and store2).

Comment: ok, but why 2 (3?)

Comment: @e4c5 Store3 was never listed in the city table but it is technically still a store type.

Comment: but that is not relevent for the readers.

Comment: The trouble with this is in your data. Your data is store as strings probably in a var char field. When sorted as strings and not as number

Comment: Item column is of the type number.

Comment: well then update your question to post numeric data instead of these strings.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
SELECT I.CEO_Name, J.num_stores, I.max_items

FROM
(SELECT S.CEO_Name, MAX(Items) AS max_items
FROM Store S
INNER JOIN City C ON C.Store_Type = S.Store_Type
GROUP BY S.CEO_Name) I

INNER JOIN

(SELECT S.CEO_Name, COUNT(DISTINCT S.Store_Type) AS num_stores
FROM Store S
INNER JOIN City C ON C.Store_type = S.Store_type
GROUP BY S.CEO_Name) J ON I.CEO_Name = J.CEO_Name

ORDER BY I.CEO_Name
```

The query consists of joining two subqueries to calculate the max_items and num_stores aggregations and then joining on CEO_Name.

Comment: I thought the database software being used was MySQL not Oracle (as per the tag)? Anyways made a small edit to possibly resolve.